# Upload files to GCS, skip if existed using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a GCS called `my-gcs` with inconsistent subfolder such as;

```
parent-path/path1/path2/*
parent-path/path3/path4/path5/*
parent-path/path6/*
```

The files can be `parquet`/`csv` or other than this.

This is my function to copy the entire folder from local to GCS:

```
def upload_local_directory_to_gcs(src_path, dest_path, data_backup, file_name):
    """
    Upload the whole directory to GCS
    """
    logger.debug("Uploading directory...")

    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(key_path)
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(GCS_BUCKET)

    if os.path.isfile(src_path):
        blob = bucket.blob(os.path.join(dest_path, os.path.basename(src_path)))
        blob.upload_from_filename(src_path)
        return

    for item in glob.glob(src_path + '/*'):

        file_exist = check_file_exist(data_backup, file_name)

        if os.path.isfile(item):
            print(item)

            if file_exist is False:
                blob = bucket.blob(os.path.join(dest_path, os.path.basename(item)),
                                   chunk_size=10485760)
                blob.upload_from_filename(item)
            else:
                logger.warning("Skipping upload. File already existed")

        else:
            if file_exist is False:
                upload_local_directory_to_gcs(item, os.path.join(dest_path, os.path.basename(item)),
                                            data_backup, file_name)
            else:
                logger.warning("Skipping upload. File already existed")
```

This is the function to check if specific file exist in the directory & sub-directory:

```
def check_file_exist(dataset, file_name):
    """
    Check if files existed
    """
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(key_path)
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(GCS_BUCKET)

    logger.debug("Checking if file already existed in GCS to skip upload...")

    blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=f'parent-path{dataset}/')
    check_files = [blob.name for blob in blobs if file_name in blob.name] #  if '.' in blob.name

    return bool(len(check_files))
```

However the code is not running correctly. Say this path `parent-path/path1/path2/*` already has a file called `first_file.csv`. It will skip uploading the existing file in this path. Until it encounters a file that not yet existed, it will upload the file and overwrite the other files for all directories as well.

Where I was expecting it to only upload specific file that is not existed yet, without overwriting the other files.

I tried my best to explain... please help.

Comment: Not the solution but note that directories do not exist in Cloud Storage. This means do not check if a directory exists before conditionally calling `upload_local_directory_to_gcs()`. For each file, you are listing all objects. Instead, list the objects, save them, and then compare in memory for each object. Your code will work for a small bucket, but once it gets large the time will expand dramatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look to the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html), you can see that on the Name property of the blob

> The name of the blob. This corresponds to the unique path of the object in the bucket.

That means the value is not only the file name, but the fully qualified path + the name `path/to/file.csv`

If your loop, you check if a file name (`file.csv` for example) is included in the blob path. Consider this case

```
path/to/file.csv
path/to/to/file.csv
```

If you test is `file.csv` exists, both blobs will return true.

To fix your issue, you need to

- Either compare the strict equality of the target_path + file_name and the blob.name
- Or include an additional condition in your "if" to include the bucket path to check in addition to the file name.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion! I fixed as what you recommended using strict equality. Can't believe I missed that out